# How can I render a template outside of a controller in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to render a template outside of a controller in my Rails 3 application. The googling I've done has been helpful, and I eventually found some useful info at http://www.swombat.com/rails-rendering-templates-outside-of-a-contro. However, this seems to be broken in Rails 3. Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this method or perhaps know of a better approach?

My method:

```
  def render_erb(template_path, params)  
   view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})  

   class << view  
    include ApplicationHelper  
   end  

   view.render(:file => "#{template_path}.html.erb", :locals => params)  
  end
```

The error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: ActionView::Template::Error
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/mikegerstenblatt/Desktop/bluetrain/lib/test.html.erb:17:in `_lib_test_html_erb__366962844_2173671680_68830'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `render'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `_render_template'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
    from /Users/mikegerstenblatt/Desktop/bluetrain/app/models/generated_website.rb:45:in `render_erb'
    from (irb):2
```

Answer (score 8):

I made a [blog post](http://www.amberbit.com/blog/2011/12/27/render-views-and-partials-outside-controllers-in-rails-3/) and a [gist](https://gist.github.com/756213) that explains it.

Essentially you need to do this:

```
class HelloWorldController < AbstractController::Base
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include AbstractController::Layouts
  include AbstractController::Helpers
  include AbstractController::Translation
  include AbstractController::AssetPaths
  include ActionController::UrlWriter

  self.view_paths = "app/views"

  def show; end
end
```

and then:

```
HelloWorldController.new.show
```

will return view rendered to a String.

Comment: Here's the correct blog link: http://www.amberbit.com/blog/2011/12/27/render-views-and-partials-outside-controllers-in-rails-3/

Comment: For Rails 4, I had to add an include for ActionView::Layouts: "include ActionView::Layouts".

Comment: On my side, for Rails 4, include as well ActionView::Rendering

Answer (score 6):

You can use render_anywhere gem to render the template outside of controller.
https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere

Answer (score 4):

Building on from the approach that Hubert suggested, I ended up with the following in my Rails 3.1 project.

I needed to render a partial in a normal view and also re-use it in an asset (under app/assets/javascripts)

```
<%
class FauxController < AbstractController::Base
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  # I didn't need layouts, translation or assetpaths, YMMV
  include AbstractController::Helpers
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  helper MyHelper # the partial references some helpers in here 

  # Make sure we can find views:
  self.view_paths = Rails.application.config.paths["app/views"]

  def show
    render :partial => "/my_controller/my_partial.js"
  end
end

%>
<%= FauxController.new.show %>
```